# Параллельное выполнение запросов telegram бота

Tags: python, telegram

Всем привет. Такая проблема: мой бот выполняет ряд операций и на это требуется определенное время. Решил попробовать выполнить сразу два запроса с двух разных устройств, на одном выдало ошибку, а на другом все сработало. Хотел узнать, как реализовать параллельное выполнение двух запросов независимо друг от друга?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def command_c(message):
    if message.text == '/start':            
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Input')

        @bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
        def input_text(message):

            def a(data):
                name = ''
                leters = string.ascii_lowercase
                num_s = string.digits
                .....

            def main():
                text = message.text
                print(text)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Alright, wait please')
                .....

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

код в целом представляет из себя что-то вроде этого.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе пример вашего кода

Comment: @gil9red Добавил

Comment: А как называется используемый модуль для работы с телеграммом? Например, с python-telegram-bot. Кст, посмотрите https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/288 мб вам это поможет

Comment: модуль PyTelegramBotAPI ,я читал про способ с webhook'ом и про способ с декоратором @run_async, но как-то безуспешно

Comment: Вроде решил, над всеми декораторами поставил @run_async, и добавил updater = Updater(TOKEN, workers=32). Хотя и без этого почему-то стало срабатывать. Тем не менее надо разбираться